# Error with 'Color' attribute in kotlin compose

Tags: android, kotlin, attributes

I just started a new project using compose. The first tutorial step was to change the color in the following way. I get an error and can't find out way. It's just 1 extra line of code, so I feel like it can't be that difficult finding the error. I just can't find it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDWGA.png)

```
package com.example.kotlin_compose_tutorial

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.kotlin_compose_tutorial.ui.theme.KotlincomposetutorialTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            KotlincomposetutorialTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        color = Color.Blue
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    KotlincomposetutorialTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

This is the entire code on the page.

I also copied and pasted this code block from the Android developer page and get the same error.

```
@Composable
fun BlueText() {
    Text("Hello World", color = Color.Blue)
}
```

Comment: The error is: 
'Unsolved reference: Color'

Comment: You need to import the class. Hover your cursor over the red word, and the IDE will present an option to add the import line for you (so you don't have to know the full package name by heart or type it out).

Comment: The 'Color' attribute doesn't have an error now, but the Blue attribute does

Answer (score 1):

It looks like as if you haven't imported the Color class. Therefore the reference "Color" is unsolved. Make sure to add this to your imports:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the wrong class was imported. The default one that got imported was not meant for Compose. It should've been
`import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color`

I guess a rookie mistake.